# Returning strings showing all vertices from all polygons in shapefile using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, polygon, vertices, list, string

I want to have a string showing all vertices from all polygons in a shapefile. In my example below my code lists all vertices and the first column shows the polygon they are part of (I only have 2 in this example)

```
import arcpy
fc=r'D:\GIS Data\TOOLS\EV calc in Python\Data.gdb\PolyWGS84'

myList = []

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,['OID@','SHAPE@']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        array1=row[1].getPart()
        for vertice in range(row[1].pointCount):
            pnt=array1.getObject(0).getObject(vertice)
            print row[0],pnt.X,pnt.Y
            myList.append(str(pnt.X) + " " + str(pnt.Y))

print ", ".join(myList)
```

This is the result

```
1 151.513429431 -33.568900991
1 151.313554706 -34.011480738
1 150.928082023 -33.975788823
1 150.906666874 -34.27560091
1 150.506917425 -34.211355462
1 150.692515384 -33.51893231
1 151.513429431 -33.568900991
2 151.72520146 -32.500522999
2 152.082120611 -33.242914833
2 151.196961117 -33.100147173
2 151.72520146 -32.500522999
151.513429431 -33.568900991, 151.313554706 -34.011480738, 150.928082023 -33.975788823, 150.906666874 -34.27560091, 150.506917425 -34.211355462, 150.692515384 -33.51893231, 151.513429431 -33.568900991, 151.72520146 -32.500522999, 152.082120611 -33.242914833, 151.196961117 -33.100147173, 151.72520146 -32.500522999
```

But what I want is separate strings for each polygon in the shapefile

```
151.513429431 -33.568900991, 151.313554706 -34.011480738, 150.928082023 -33.975788823, 150.906666874 -34.27560091, 150.506917425 -34.211355462, 150.692515384 -33.51893231, 151.513429431 -33.568900991
151.72520146 -32.500522999, 152.082120611 -33.242914833, 151.196961117 -33.100147173, 151.72520146 -32.500522999
```

How would you do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the general idea in place already -- just move your print of the list into the loop, and remove the print for each vertex.

```
import arcpy
fc=r'D:\GIS Data\TOOLS\EV calc in Python\Data.gdb\PolyWGS84'



with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,['OID@','SHAPE@']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        myList = []
        array1=row[1].getPart()
        for vertice in range(row[1].pointCount):
            pnt=array1.getObject(0).getObject(vertice)
            # print row[0],pnt.X,pnt.Y
            myList.append(str(pnt.X) + " " + str(pnt.Y))
        print row[0], ", ".join(myList)
```