# Concatenating list of strings using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, polygon, vertices, list, string

My code from [Returning strings showing all vertices from all polygons in shapefile using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/328917) creates is the following:

```
import arcpy

fc=r'D:\GIS Data\TOOLS\EV calc in Python\Data.gdb\PolyWGS842'

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,['OID@','SHAPE@']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        myList = []
        array1=row[1].getPart()
        for vertice in range(row[1].pointCount):
            pnt=array1.getObject(0).getObject(vertice)
            #print row[0],pnt.X,pnt.Y
            myList.append(str(pnt.X) + " " + str(pnt.Y))

        a = "((" + ", ".join(myList) + "))"
        print a
```

Outputs this:

```
((150.523124571 -32.391945847, 150.904615846 -32.362024963, 151.129022478 -32.603885445, 150.784932308 -32.843252519, 150.525617978 -32.696141505, 150.523124571 -32.391945847))
((151.168916991 -32.843252519, 151.405790658 -33.040231674, 151.308547784 -33.214770166, 151.019312569 -33.125007513, 151.168916991 -32.843252519))
((150.568005897 -33.234717422, 150.894642218 -33.090099815, 150.919576288 -33.511485602, 150.570499304 -33.501511974, 150.568005897 -33.234717422))
```

But I would like to concatenate the strings with a come, like this:

```
((150.523124571 -32.391945847, 150.904615846 -32.362024963, 151.129022478 -32.603885445, 150.784932308 -32.843252519, 150.525617978 -32.696141505, 150.523124571 -32.391945847)), ((151.168916991 -32.843252519, 151.405790658 -33.040231674, 151.308547784 -33.214770166, 151.019312569 -33.125007513, 151.168916991 -32.843252519)), ((150.568005897 -33.234717422, 150.894642218 -33.090099815, 150.919576288 -33.511485602, 150.570499304 -33.501511974, 150.568005897 -33.234717422))
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to wrap the final result within double parentesis? Also, Are you ceoncerned that you are building a string and not a tuple (is this what you want)?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to build a string that I will later need to pass to a SQL statement using pymssql. the double parenthesis is needed to specify the coordinates for a multipolygon, see example [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stmpolyfromtext-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I gave you an answer that should do what you want

Comment: Keep in mind that multi-part polygons also exist. WKT for MULTIPOLYGON has a triple-paren, with comma-delimited double-paren for parts, in addition to single-paren nested sub-parts (holes).  This approach is HIGHLY dependent on very simple polygons. A far more reliable approach would be to use the `shape@WKT` source designator.

Comment: @Vince This is interesting, but wouldn't that give me the same result? I am passing:
`for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ["SHAPE@WKT"]):
  print row[0]`
And it gives me back:
`MULTIPOLYGON (((150.56800589700003 -33.23471742199996, 150.57049930400001 -33.501511973999982, 150.91957628800003 -33.511485601999937, 150.89464221800006 -33.090099814999974, 150.56800589700003 -33.23471742199996)))`

Comment: @vince My idea is to pass a SQL statement similar to this example to run a query using pymssql 
`SET @g = geometry::STMPolyFromText('MULTIPOLYGON (((5 5, 10 5, 10 10, 5 5)), ((10 10, 100 10, 200 200, 30 30, 10 10)))', 0)`

Comment: It would only give the same result if you coded the inner loop to handle multi-part polygons with sub-parts correctly (and these answers do not).  Writing your own WKT encoder is not very efficient, but if you do it, you need to do it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue here is that you're trying to *reinvent the wheel*. ArcGIS already has a fully functional Well-Known Text generator built into the `da.SearchCursor` and `Geometry` objects. This generator handles both polygons with sub-parts (aka holes), and multi-polygons (potentially with sub-parts), so using the `shape@WKT` column tag removes the need for list concatenation:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,['OID@','SHAPE@WKT']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print(row[1])
```

Comment: Thank you! You are right saying using shape@WKT is more correct otherwise I won't be able to deal with sub-parts. I have changed my code to:
` with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,['OID@','SHAPE@WKT']) as cursor:
    myList = []
    for row in cursor:
        myList.append(row[1][14:][:-1])
    a = "MULTIPOLYGON (" + ", ".join(myList) + ")"
    print a`

Comment: No, that's not right either. There is no need to make a one-element list and use `join` on it. If the result could be POLYGON or MULTIPOLYGON, erasing the first 14 characters is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to create another list which then contains your individual `a` variables. Finally, we then concatenate those outside the loop.
Hence:

```
outer_list = []    
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,['OID@','SHAPE@']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        myList = []
        array1=row[1].getPart()
        for vertice in range(row[1].pointCount):
            pnt=array1.getObject(0).getObject(vertice)
            myList.append(str(pnt.X) + " " + str(pnt.Y))

        a = "((" + ", ".join(myList) + "))"
        outer_list.append(a)
    print(", ".join(outer_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just declare your variable `a` outside of the main loop and de-indent the final print like so (not tested):

```
import arcpy

fc=r'D:\GIS Data\TOOLS\EV calc in Python\Data.gdb\PolyWGS842'

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,['OID@','SHAPE@']) as cursor:
    a = "((" # ADD THIS
    for row in cursor:
        myList = []
        array1=row[1].getPart()
        for vertice in range(row[1].pointCount):
            pnt=array1.getObject(0).getObject(vertice)
            #print row[0],pnt.X,pnt.Y
            myList.append(str(pnt.X) + " " + str(pnt.Y))

        a += ", ".join(myList) # CHANGE THIS
    a += "))"
    print a # DE-INDENT OUT OF THE MAIN LOOP
```

Comment: Thanks, almost there but it would not keep the parentheses in the middle

Comment: no worries, although in you question your aim was to only have parenthesis at the beginning and end. Anyways, glad you found a solution. Cheers.